# how can I connect netbeans(ruby on rails project) with source safe (Vss)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans, visual-sourcesafe, netbeans-plugins, visual-sourcesafe-plugin

how can I connect netbeans(ruby on rails project) with source safe (Vss) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqVSSProfile

Comment: thanks

i am facing problem while Configuration of VSS in NetBeans 6.8 IDE.
i get error like :

"Missing required modules for Plugin VCS Core:
Master Filesystem [module org.netbeans.modules.masterfs/1 > 1.1]"
here VCS Core is for VSS Plugin.

what I do for this error ?